# How to make clang-format indent all detail namespaces by one

Tags: c++, clang-format

How can I make clang-format indent all `*detail*` and anonymous namespaces in C++ by one tab space (whatever that is, I am using 4 space tabs)

Comment: I don't think that's possible.  At least I didn't see any option like that in the [docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html).

Comment: @HenriMenke  Is there any other formatting program that can handle things like this and is commonly used?

Comment: The only other indenter I know of is [GNU indent](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) but this likely has *fewer* features than `clang-format` rather than more (and it's designed for plain C, not C++).

Comment: That's unfortunate , I will wait to see if anyone else has an idea about what to do here

Comment: Maybe `NamespaceIndentation: Inner` would be close to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

For indenting namespaces in general you can use this:

`NamespaceIndentation: All`